# Ms Dynamics Crm 2011 : Browser based user login from Desktop application

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have a scenario where we need to do direct login in Microsoft Dynamics Crm web application from the desktop application.We tried couple of approcahes like login from url i.e providing username and password in url and creating webpage having fields similar to crm login page but no success.

Note:We dont need passport authentication scenario as it is for desktop login only.

Comment: What is "the desktop application"?

Comment: Basically we have winform application from where we are trying to do weblogin of crm.In our scenario (1)User will create activity (2)If activity get created then we want to open "Newly Created Activty" webpage of crm.(3)Currently,we are able to open new created activty page only if user is already logged in the CRM.But if user is not logged in,then user is redirected to login page.To overcome this issue we are trying for weblogin of crm from desktop application

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if this is going to answer the question since there isn't much listed about what language, technologies, etc you are using, but this may be what you are looking for.  If not please provide more on what you are doing, and preferably some sample code.

Assuming you are using .NET for your app, if you download the SDK there are some helper dlls and one of those provides a dialog that gives you a connection to different types of CRM deployment including IFD, Windows, O365, live, etc.

Here is a link to the [SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.windows.controls.connectiondialog.connectiondialog.aspx) on it, and here is a [good article](http://community.adxstudio.com/blogs/shan/2012-04-25-crm-connection-dialog/) on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply.In our scenario (1)User will create activity (2)If activity get created then we want to open "Newly Created Activty" webpage of crm.(3)Currently,we are able to open new created activty page only if user is already logged in the CRM.But if user is not logged in,then user is redirected to  login page.To overcome this issue we are trying for weblogin of crm from desktop application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It makes sense now.  However I don't believe there is any way (at least easily) to do what you are looking for.  Once you leave the app and are on the browser it isn't aware of any authentication you have already done.  Essentially I believe there is a token, auth header, or cookie depending on your auth method that gets stored in the browser, and I am not aware of any way to do that.    

There are ways to auto-login if you are using windows login with your browser settings.  If it is something more complicated I don't think there is a way.